# Build Namecoin from source

Tags: namecoin

I'm trying to install the current version of namecoin from github.

After much trouble and poking around, I found the official install instructions here:https://github.com/namecoin/wiki/wiki/Build-Namecoin-From-Source

Instructions are:

```
git clone https://github.com/namecoin/namecoin.git
cd namecoin/src
make -f makefile.unix namecoind
```

Only problem, there is no makefile.unix, only MakeFile and makefile.mingw

Anyone get through something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Makefile` in that directory appears to be a perfectly good makefile. Perhaps the build instructions are out of date. So try:

```
make namecoind
```

(without the `-f` option, the `make` program automatically reads the file named `Makefile`).

Comment: So far so good, seems to be compiling. One last question, if I may, I tried running make namecoind USE_UPNP=- yet I get fatal error: miniupnpc/miniwget.h: No such file or directory. How do I flag no UPnP?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps try `USE_UPNP=` (that is, without anything at all after the `=`).

Comment: make USE_UPNP=' ' for namecoin-qt